# Override font smoothing (antialiasing) method in Google Sheets grid (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, fonts, google-spreadsheets, anti-aliasing, font-smoothing

How to override font smoothing used in Google Sheets grid to make fonts sharp (as everywhere else on a page)?

As you can see from the screenshot below, most of the elements use sharp font (standard Windows smoothing, not Clear Type). Even text in a cell edit textbox is OK (see 'World' word). But column names (A, B, C, D, E), row names  (1, 2, 3) and cells content (see 'Hello' word).

I tried to analyze the grid using Developer Tools (F12) but it looks as a single element and whichever style I apply to it , it has little to no effect.

A custom style (`font-family: sans-serif !important;`) has been applied to the page using Stylus  extension.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you're after here. See this zoomed image. Hello is antialiased [though with some nasty blue shift] World isn't antialiased at all, it looks like a staircase. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRc0d.png

Comment: @Tetsujin I want all text in grid to look like 'World'. But currently it is all rendered as 'Hello'.

Comment: Added another screenshot for better explanation.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?